# Select the three first divs

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In CSS I want to select the three first divs. I have this code:

```css
div:nth-child(3n) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore laborum necessitatibus nobis obcaecati, mollitia, eos sint dolor odit. Possimus dolores recusandae sed totam, voluptatibus, voluptatum. Voluptatibus minus aut, quam ratione.
</div>

<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates perferendis et saepe omnis nemo, dolores quia ipsam ea blanditiis quaerat autem aut id itaque magnam recusandae sint architecto! Error, consequuntur.
</div>

<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem doloremque quis perspiciatis vel odio impedit itaque laborum eveniet quasi aperiam, autem cumque vero recusandae, voluptates et nesciunt quibusdam aliquid! Deleniti.
</div>

<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem doloremque quis perspiciatis vel odio impedit itaque laborum eveniet quasi aperiam, autem cumque vero recusandae, voluptates et nesciunt quibusdam aliquid! Deleniti.
</div>
```

I try above CSS but it does not work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not working as expected because `:nth-child(3n)` will select every third element.

You need to select every element starting from the third one counting backwards, therefore you could use `-n + 3` or `-1n + 3`.

In other words, given the pattern `an+b`, `a` should be `1` (or omitted) since you don't want to skip over elements. In addition, `a` should also be negative and `b` should be `3` since you're starting at the third element.

```css
div:nth-child(-1n + 3) {
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div>One</div>
<div>Two</div>
<div>Three</div>
<div>Four</div>
<div>Five</div>
```

It's worth pointing out that `div:nth-child(-1n + 3)` will only select the element if it is one of the first three elements and also an element type `div`. In other words, if the third element is a `span`, only the first two `div` elements will be selected:

```css
div:nth-child(-1n + 3) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>First div</div>
<div>Second div</div>
<span>Span</span>
<div>Third div</div>
```

If the element types vary (like above), then you should use [`:nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) instead:

```css
div:nth-of-type(-1n + 3) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>First div</div>
<div>Second div</div>
<span>Span</span>
<div>Third div</div>
```