# How can I select all the element except last 3 element?

Tags: html, css

How to apply CSS **margin-bottom: 30px;** all the element except last 3 element; element count can be any number

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="card"></div>
   <div class="card"></div>
   <div class="card"></div>
   <div class="card"></div>
   <div class="card"></div>
   <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use "div:nth-child()"

Comment: The title is confusing. I edited it so as to better reflect your intention in accordance with the accepted answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select the three first divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35344129/select-the-three-first-divs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a pseudo-elements `nth-child()` and `nth-last-child()`

```css
.container .card:nth-child(-n+3) {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.container .card:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
       <div class="card">test</div>
       <div class="card">test</div>
       <div class="card">test</div>
       <div class="card">test</div>
       <div class="card">test</div>
       <div class="card">test</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The "last-child" example is missing the number "3" as well as a colon ":" after the margin-bottom property. Should be `.container .card:nth-last-child(-n+3) {margin-bottom: 0px;}`

Comment: Thank you for a good note. I wrote the code quickly and did not pay attention to that

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained your answer instead of just dumping code

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pseudo element called `nth-child()`. This picks particular childs. In this case, you would use

```css
.card:nth-child(-n+3) {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.card:nth-child(-n+3) {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="card">7</div>
   <div class="card">6</div>
   <div class="card">5</div>
   <div class="card">4</div>
   <div class="card">3</div>
   <div class="card">2</div>
   <div class="card">1</div>
</div>
```

You use n as a variable. At n = 1, nth-child will be 2, n = 2, nth-child will be 1 and n = 3 nth-child will be 0. It won't go on to have negative a nth-child.

Let me know if it works!

Comment: this code is not working well it is not leaving the margin in last 3 child ?

Comment: @XMehdi01 That's the desired result that was indicated in the question

Answer (score 0):

I can do it with `:nth-child()` and `:not()` selector.

```css
div.container .card:nth-child(n+1):not(:nth-child(n+4)) {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">data 1</div>
  <div class="card">data 2</div>
  <div class="card">data 3</div>
  <div class="card">data 4</div>
  <div class="card">data 5</div>
  <div class="card">data 6</div>
</div>
```